# How do I set an img title attribute with html entities in Angular?

Tags: angular, html-entities

From the backend I will receive strings like '© Acme'.
Now I have the problem setting these as title attributes to img tags.

[title] or [attr.title] will set the string as it is (`&copy;`, not ©)

and I have not been able to figure out a directive or pipe that helps to render html entities in the attribute. With a directive like this

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Inject, Input, OnInit, Renderer2, SecurityContext} from '@angular/core';
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Directive({
  selector: '[trustedTitle]'
})
export class TrustedTitleDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input() trustedTitle: string;

  constructor(@Inject(DomSanitizer) private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const safeHtml = this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, this.trustedTitle);
    console.log('Trusted Title:', safeHtml);
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'title', safeHtml);
  }

}
```

for example I end up with a title displaying `&#169; Acme`.

BTW: I'm using an Angular version ^4.0.0.

---

### Update:

The problem seems to be that the javascript string variable needs to be reparsed. This now seems obvious and usually I would of course have done it using `[innerHtml]`. But since I had to deal with the title attribute only I ended up with a custom component for now:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[trustedTitle]'
})
export class TrustedTitleDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input() trustedTitle: string;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.el.nativeElement.title = this.parseHtmlTextStr(this.trustedTitle);
  }

  /**
   * Parses HTML Entities in a string.
   * return parsed string or fall back to original.
   */
  parseHtmlTextStr(str: string): string {

   const temp = document.createElement('template');
   temp.innerHTML = str;
   str = temp.innerHTML;

   temp.remove();
   return str;
 }
}
```

This looks and feels still very hacky to me. So if someone comes up with something more elegant it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use DomSanitizationService

Working plunkr
https://plnkr.co/edit/B5qWrcriBtCNghae39DQ?p=preview

```
//our root app component
import {Component, Pipe} from '@angular/core'
import {DomSanitizationService} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',

  template: `
   <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42" [title]="getSanitizedContent('&copy;avb')">

  `,
})
export class AppComponent {

  dangerousUrl='&copy;';

  constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizationService) {
  }

  getSanitizedContent(abc:String){
    console.log(this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(abc));
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(abc).changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity;
  }

}
```

**Edit:**
DomSanitizationService is removed & now we have DomSanitizer in Angular4

```
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Full Sample Code:

Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

  constructor(public sanitizer:DomSanitizer){

  }

   getSanitizedContent(abc:string){
    console.log(this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(abc));
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(abc)["changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity"];
  }
}
```

Template:

```
   <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42" [title]="getSanitizedContent('&copy;avb')">
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply and plunkr. Despite what I wrote in the question headline I'm using Angular version ^4.0.0 in the project (Sorry for that) and this version does not seem to have an exported service DomSanitizationService in @angular/platform-browser. Do you have any idea how to implement this in Angular4 (again sorry!)?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But this still does not solve my problem. Your solution only works when you put the string directly in the template as you did in the example. In this case the html is already rendered in the template, debugging shows that "©avb" is already passed to the getSanatizedContent  fn. 
When passing a variable the html is not resolved and I end up with 
`SafeHtmlImpl {changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity: "&copy;avb"}`.

Comment: @hsvp: Just to understand, i.e u will do manipulations in component itself right.

Answer (score 0):

DOMSanitizer

Potential unsafe HTML needs to be explicitly marked as trusted using Angulars DOM sanitizer so doesn't strip potentially unsafe parts of the content.

HTML:

```
  <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42" 
  [innerHTML]="safeHtml">
```

with a pipe like

```
 @Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml' })
   export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) { }
      transform(value) {
      return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
    }
  }
```